# Environment variables in Zabbix's host

Tags: oracle, environment-variables, unixodbc, zabbix

I want to have a graph from queries to Oracle. I can connect to remote Oracle with isql and sqlplus. But in Zabbix host has an error:

> Cannot connect to ODBC DSN:[SQL_ERROR]:[IM002][0][[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified]|

I guess Zabbix needs (updated) LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH environment variables which I have edited in my command line.

How can I set environment variables in Zabbix's host?

Comment: Could you please show the `isql` command line you use to connect and Zabbix item settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all this problem had nothing to do with environment variables, it even worked without them. My problem was that I configured `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files from `/usr/local/etc`. That is the place `isql/sqlplus` uses them and `odbcinst -j` command shows them to be. **But Zabbix uses them from** `/etc`. (I found this tip somewhere from Stackoverflow or like that web page but can't find it anymore)